# Why can't I add a plain link tag in Rails4 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Why is it so forbidden to add line like `<link href="/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">` in my `application.html.erb` file. How else do I insert it?

Comment: did you also try `stylesheet_link_tag`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "forbidden" outright - it just skirts a lot of important Rails [**conventions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) which will likely create problems & inconsistencies down the line

There are several elements to what you're asking. Here they are:

---

**Layout**

Firstly, you need to use the correct `helpers` in your layout:

```
#app/views/layout/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap/bootsrap" %>
```

The reason for this is the same as using helpers in other parts of your Rails application - as paths change between environments & certain "backend" functionalities of the system evolve, you can't rely on using vanilla HTML to call "Rails-centric" methods

A pro tip is that if there is *any* reference to a path, or an asset, you need to [use the helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html) which Rails provides

---

**Asset Pipeline**

Further to this, you need to appreciate how the "asset pipeline" works.

One of the big benefits of the Rails framework is that it gives you the ability to organize your assets in the most effective way - by keeping them in the `/assets` folder.

Whilst great for development, your problem will arise when you go into a production environment - Rails prefers to [serve static assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production) in production, which means that the assets will be pre-compiled & access in the `public` folder:

> In the production environment Sprockets uses the fingerprinting scheme
>   outlined above. By default Rails assumes assets have been precompiled
>   and will be served as static assets by your web server.

To make sure this works properly, you **need to use the path helpers** to load the files dynamically; hence allowing Rails to access the files wherever they are on the system

--

**Manifest**

I would *strongly* recommend you look into the ["manifest" feature](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) of the asset pipeline:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
/*
 *= require bootstrap/bootstrap
*/
```

Comment: Good explanation. I had put files in `assets/` but `stylesheet_link_tag` was looking in `/public/` folder